# How can I write an if else-if else query in MySQL when returning variable number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three columns in a table:

```
score  status  No.
1,     2,      1
0,     1,      2
0,     0,      1
```

I need this, to write a C# style pseudo SQL:

```
rows = empty;

rows = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE score = 1"
if (rows.Count > 0) //at least one row
    return rows;

rows = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status = 2"
if (rows.Count > 1) //more than one row 
    return row with MAX(No.) from rows; //ie MAX(No.) where status = 2

 return rows;
```

I hope I could be clear. In short, select from my table records with score = 1, and if there isn't such a record, return the record where status = 2 and if there are more than one record with status = 2, then return the record with maximum value for No. where status = 2 (if no record at all with status = 2, return empty).

How can I write it in one query? It should be a good learning experience for me. Otherwise I know to breakup into smaller queries and run each one. And I can't go with stored procedures right now..

**Edit:** Actually my query will have a few more WHERE clauses but identical in both the conditions and that is why I omitted it. Hence, regarding the first condition, there will be only one record returned for now. That is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE score = 1` will return just one row for now. And **I need / I'll accept answers** that gives such a solution too. But the point is you never know, may be in future with some design changes, there could be more rows with `score = 1`. That is why I went for **records** instead of **record**. But ideally the business logic is to have all records with `score = 1`. For now, record will do. I'm just thinking query will be much simpler if only one row is returned and my teammates can assimilate the code easily.

**Final Update**: Thank you all guys, you've been very kind :) Many answers worked well, and choosing one is really really daunting. My finding on the answers:

1. Answers which worked always: [@GordonLinoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11417683/661933), [@ZaneBiens's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511648/661933), [@ZaneBien's another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11446343/661933), [@Scen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512028/661933), [@JulienCh.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404254/661933) (the last 3 being essentially the same, but yet I am not fully aware how those worked :))
2. Answers which worked only when first condition `score = 1` returned only one row: [@HannoBinder's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509577/661933), [@ShlomiNoach's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412137/661933), [@DaniellePaquette-Harvey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11459076/661933). For the moment, I 'll stick with @Danielle's (which is freakingly simple) and later revert if there arises need to have more than one row)
3. Rest of the answers, I couldn't test as they were either not very specific or not related to MySQL.
4. [@MatthewPK's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680027/661933) is not appropriate in the context.

Awarding the bounty and accepting an answer is tough with so many right answers. I chose [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511648/661933) since I felt it is probably more efficient and readable too, but I'll accept @Scen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512028/661933) for being downright simple.

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't work. It will never reach the second condition

Comment: @MatthewPK why wouldn't it reach? I just provided a sample set of values. I worry I missed something key?

Comment: In the first case, are you looking for all rows that match the condition or just one?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am looking for all rows in the first condition. That is why I wrote `return rows`. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @nawfal Please update the description because it says `a record` (singular), not `all records` (plural)

Comment: Your description contradicts your code. The code indicates that the row with the maximum No. is returned when there are at least two rows with status=2. However, your description indicates that you just want the row with the maximum No. when there is at least one row with status=2

Comment: Wait a minute, if there are 2 or more rows where `status = 2`, do you want to return the max `No.` for the entire table ***regardless*** of status or score, or do you just want the max `No.` ***where*** status = 2?

Comment: @DaveF they both are essentially the same right? ;) No contradiction. Please mention name while commenting, I am not notified otherwise.

Comment: @ZaneBien oops really sorry for not mentioning that. I want max(No) where status = 2; I will edit it..

Comment: Okay, great! My solution still stands. Thanks.

Comment: @nawfal No they aren't. In the code, rows.Count > 1 would only return the maximum row when there are 2 or more rows where status=2, meaning that a single row with status=2 wouldn't be returned because there is no code to return it. However, in your comments you stated that you wanted the row returned when there is only one row with status=2, meaning your code should be rows.Count > 0. I follows the comments when I wrote my answer, but the very first time I read your question I was attempting to solve the problem based on the code.

Comment: @DaveF, look closer: The very last `return` at the bottom would return the result of the second query if the condition `rows.Count > 1` did not satisfy. If the condition `rows.Count > 1` is not satisfied, it skips over the execution of `return rows with MAX(no)...` and goes straight to the last `return` instead, which would either return one row or an empty result. If `rows.Count > 1` ***is*** satisfied, it executes `return rows with MAX(no)...` and the last `return` is not executed.

Comment: @nawfal I'm sorry. You're correct. The rows=empty at the front threw me off. I'd assumed that it was being initialized in order to return empty when no conditions were met and wasn't thinking about how the queries overwrite it.

The answer that I wrote should work since I went of the comments following the code and not the false assumption that I'd made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select *
From scores
Where score = 1
UNION
(
   Select *
   From scores
   Where status = 2 and not exists (Select * from scores where score = 1)
   Order By `No.` desc
   Limit 1
);
```

I named `table` as `scores`.

SqlFiddle (Query with some fake schema so you can see the results):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aac2/1/0

EDIT: edited SQlFiddle to match the fake schema with the one in the question.

Comment: Isnt this @JulienCh. 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404254/661933) exactly? Moreover what has `and exists (Select * from scores where score = 1 Limit 1)` got to do in first query?  There is no need of limit 1 in exists queries btw..

Comment: Well, the reason you posed the question was to create a clear query for others to use, correct? It's not exactly like @JulienCh's answer because the syntax is different. It is the same result, and both will probably turn into the same query in the end anyway.

Comment: I get that, nice intention, but avoiding quite "obvious things" will actually clear confusions in my experience. Ya towards the end your queries are different, and I like yours more, but otherwise they are just the same :)

Comment: I also didn't see his answer. I voted it up after I read it. :P

Answer (score 5):

This seems hard, since you are returning a variable number of rows in the two cases.

The following query combines all possible rows, and then check on the presence of the first type to see which type should be returned.

```
select *
from ((SELECT 'SCORE' as matchtype, t.*
       FROM `table` t
       WHERE score = 1
      ) union all
      (SELECT 'STATUS' as matchtype, t.*
       FROM `table` t join
            (select max(`No.`) as maxno
             from `table` 
             WHERE status = 2
           ) tsum
           on t.`No.` = tsum.maxno
       WHERE status = 2
      )
     ) t cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from `table`
      where score = 1
     ) const
where matchtype = (case when const.cnt > 0 then 'SCORE' else 'STATUS' end)
```

Note:  the return set includes the MatchType.  To get rid of this, you would need to include the full list of desired columns.

Comment: This fixes the bug in my own solution, where only one row is returned (clarification was only made at later stage).

Answer (score 4):

This query will solve your question:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `your_table`
WHERE
  status = 2 OR score = 1 
ORDER BY
  if(score = 1, 1, 0) DESC, 
  if(status = 2, 1, 0) DESC,
  `No.` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

As opposed to other answers:

- It does not assume positive values for the column `No.`
- This is MySQL syntax (you have tagged as `mysql`)

But do feel free to give the credit/reputation to KSiimson, who laid out the right path. His query has two bugs, unfortunately.

Also note that said query cannot utilize any index on the `ORDER BY` clause, since we wrap columns with functions. Indexes are unlikely to be used on the `FROM clause` because of the `OR` condition.

Comment: I appreciate the credit! Unfortunately I was doing this from Starbucks yesterday - the Wifi there had serious issues and I couldn't finish editing the query. I finished it at work this morning and saw your post; I like how it uses a separate order by clause for both `score` and `status`, so it will work even if `No.` is negative.

Comment: My own ORDER BY clause has some redundancy; it can be shortened by much. But the way it is laid right now is as readable as I can make it.
Cheers

Comment: But now I see from recent comments to the question that the author wants to get ALL rows matching the case of `score = 1`. So this solution is still incorrect...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a much more efficient solution that should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE score = 1 

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT a.* 
    FROM tbl a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS s1exists FROM tbl WHERE score = 1
    ) b ON b.s1exists = 0
    WHERE a.status = 2
    ORDER BY a.no DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

---

### Breakdown:

How this query works is that the first `SELECT` in the `UNION` returns all rows where `score` = 1. The second `SELECT` returns the maximum row (based on the `no` field) where `status` = 2 **AND** where there isn't a single row where `score` = 1. Whether there is only one row or multiple rows where `status` = 2, the maximum row is the same thing for both.

This satisfies all of your conditions that you had specified:

---

- **One or more rows exists where `score` = 1**: *First `SELECT` returns all of those rows; second `SELECT` returns empty (even if there are rows with `status` = 2).*

---

- **No rows exist where `score` = 1 and there's one row where `status` = 2**: *First `SELECT` returns empty; second `SELECT` returns one row (which is the **same** thing as the max row).*

---

- **No rows exist where `score` = 1 and there's more than one row where `status` = 2**: *First `SELECT` returns empty; second `SELECT` returns the max row where `status` = 2.*

---

- **No rows exist at all where either `score` = 1 or `status` = 2**: *First row returns nothing; second row also returns nothing, rendering an empty result.*

Comment: I had tried solving this question for a couple days similar to the way you did it here but couldn't figure out how to properly join the inner join. I like the subtle solution here of b ON b.s1exists = 0... That was what I couldn't figure out. Nice work. I like this solution over the others.

Comment: Yes, and I regret awarding bounty to the other answer. This deserved it more I feel now. Basically I was in a dilemma to choose between your two answers and somehow I went for the other. I thought the other was more efficient. Do you know which method of yours is more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Totally untested, most probably very inefficient, but might work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE score=1

union all

SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE status=2 
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE score=1)
and `No.` = (
             SELECT max(`No.`) FROM `table`
             WHERE status=2 
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only positive integers are used in `No.`:

```
select   * 
from     `table` 
where    status = 2 or score = 1 
order by if(score = 1, -2, if(status = 2, -1)), `No.` desc 
limit    1;
```

What I did was I created an expression that the rows will be ordered by. The expression will return -2 if score is one, -1 when only status is one. As a fallback, we have sorting by `No.` field in descending order.

See Shlomi Noach's solution for an improvement on this that works when `No.` field has a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the first result from this query:

```
-- If there is no row with Score 1, then the first SELECT will return nothing.
-- If there is a row with Score 1, then you will get it.
-- No row with Score 1. If there is one row with Status 2, then you will get it.
-- No row with Score 1. If there is more than one row with Status 2, then you will get the one with the highest No.

SELECT 1 AS ColumnOrder, Table.*
FROM   Table
WHERE  Score = 1
LIMIT  1
UNION ALL
SELECT   2 AS ColumnOrder, Table.* 
FROM     Table 
WHERE    Status=2 
ORDER BY ColumnOrder, No DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: I am askin for mysql. plus 1 still

Comment: This is such a freaky solution!! +100 ;) of course it works only if `score = 1` have to return just one record. But still...

Answer (score 1):

I left my original answer, but it isn't as efficient as the one below:

```
/*
Query returns rows with score=1 when they exist or nothing
*/
select score, status, no from temp where score=1

UNION

/*
Query returns rows with status=2 when they exist and when there are no rows
 with score=1 or nothing otherwise.
*/
(

select t1.score, t1.status, t1.no from

( /* <subquery> */

(
select score, status, no from temp
where status=2 and (select max(score) from temp where score=1) is null
) as t1

join

(
select max(no) as maxNo from temp where status=2
) as t2

on t1.no=t2.maxNo

) /* </subquery> */

limit 1

)
```

You can use indexes to make it more efficient. Also, I'm not certain if the query in the conditional statement (which checks if there are any rows with score=1) gets executed once or more than once. To be on the safe side, you can replace it with @c and prepend the line:

```
set @c:=(select max(score) from temp where score=1);
```

Original answer:

```
/*
Query returns rows with score=1 when they exist or nothing
*/
select score, status, no from temp where score=1

UNION

/*
Query returns nothing when there are rows with score=1,
 rows with status=2 when they exist and when there are no rows with score=1, or
 nothing otherwise.

Does this by adding weights to rows.
Rows with score=1 have greater weights than rows with status=2.
Joins rows with greatest weights to rows with status=2.
*/
( /* <query> */

select t.score, t.status, t.no from
( /* <joins> */

/* Gets greatest weight */
(
select max(if(score=1, 2, if(status=2, 1, -1))) as w
from temp
) as t1

join

/*  Joined on rows with status=2 using assigned weights */
(
select score, status, no, if(score=1, 2, if(status=2, 1, -2)) as w
from temp
where status=2
) as t

on t.w=t1.w

join

/*  Joined on rows with greatest No. for rows with status=2 */
(
select max(no) as maxNo
from temp
where status=2
) as t2

on t.no=t2.maxNo

) limit 1 /* </joins> (Only returns one row with max No.) */

) /* </query> */
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot (yet?) see any elegant solution to your problem in only *one* query.

Besides, I'm not sure what your actual problem really is; your sample code seems clear but I find it hard to extrapolate a problem that will cover your requirements from

> my query will have a few more WHERE clauses but identical in both the
>   conditions

Apart from that, I'm surprised that up to now no one proposed the use of a `group by` clause.
Not going into the syntactical details of MySQL here, but basically

```
select score, status, MAX(No) as No
from tbl 
group by score, status
```

will give you exactly the single one record per 'group' with the maximum value for `No`.

Put into a subquery the above `select` can be refined, for example

```
select *
from ( [*] ) as tbl
where
   (score = 1)
OR (score != 1 AND status = 2)
OR /* ... more conditions of the above type... */
order by /* ... */
limit 1
```

(`[*]` stands for the `group`ed select statement from above here)

Add or remove (a variant of) an `order by score DESC, status DESC` and/or `limit 1` clause as needed and you should be very close to what you need.

Comment: this is really nice way of looking at it, and the most straightforward of them all. But need not be that efficient.. Let me test it with some samples and get back to u

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work, the reason being that the inner group by behaving the weird way mysql is known for..

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce a problem with the inner query's group by. - Can you give some detail on what results you get?

Comment: I have, btw, edited my answer to make it more clear that `order by` and `limit` clauses are to be applied solely to the *outer* query.

Comment: Hanno, this doesnt work. I am not sure if I can convincingly state why. See this sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1206 . The problem is here that the limit clause at the end of the query decides ultimately how many rows should be returned, and hence it cant be a variable number of records. Furthermore, the logic itself is wrong, 'cos an `OR` condition basically fetches both when score=1 and also when score != 1 and status = 2. You can see the link for more

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean then. The logic itself is correct as long as only one record is needed as result. The case of multiple records with `score = 1` being returned is indeed not covered by this proposal. The query could be extended some more but I guess you've already solved your problem, so let's just leave it this way :)

Comment: Hanno, this wouldnt work still. See what `where
   (score = 1)
OR (score != 1 AND status = 2)` returns, and now no filtering with order by or limit etc work.

Comment: It does work for the example data from your original question where `score` was either 1 or 0. It does not work for the example data from your link indeed. If a certain value (for `score`) from the value's allowed range has a special meaning, for instance a value of 1 from 0 <= score <= 999, this often indicates a violation of the 1st normal form; you may want to check if the special meaning of the value 1 could/should be represented explicitly in the data (read: in its own (boolean?) field in the table) instead of implicitly in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(Select * From `table` Where score = 1)
Begin
    Select * From `table` Where score = 1;
End
Else
Begin
    Select *
    From `table`
    Where status = 2
    Order by `No.` desc
    LIMIT 1
End
```

Comment: I would like to do away with store procs. Isn't this one? Also accept my edit to make it mysql compatible

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't know you were trying to avoid stored procs. I made another answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11446343/1446794) but I'm posting this one as another answer because it uses a completely different technique (conditional conditions in the `WHERE` clause) rather than using `UNION`.

This avoids having to use `UNION` operators which is maybe what you're after (even though technically using `UNION` of two statements counts as "one" query). Another advantage is that it is DBMS agnostic and doesn't rely on `ORDER BY X` / `LIMIT 1` which is primarily a MySQL-based technique to retrieving minimum and maximum rows:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS score1cnt FROM tbl WHERE score = 1) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(no) AS maxno FROM tbl WHERE status = 2) c
WHERE
    CASE WHEN b.score1cnt > 0 THEN a.score = 1
         WHEN b.score1cnt = 0 AND c.maxno IS NOT NULL THEN a.status = 2 AND a.no = c.maxno
         ELSE 0
    END
```

You can fiddle around with a [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65680/4/1) which includes both of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SCORE, STATUS, NO from (
    SELECT * , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [STATUS] ORDER BY SCORE ASC, NO DESC) AS RANK
    FROM `table`
    WHERE  score = 1 OR [status] = 2 ) x
WHERE X.Rank = 1
```

Comment: are u sure rank() is supported by mysql?